# Prove: $f(A \cup B)=f(A) \cup f(B)$

Tags: solution-verification

I would like to get some feedback if this proof is rigorous and correctly written.
And if not how should it be written. Where did I go wrong etc.

Def 1: $x \in A \cup B: \Leftrightarrow \forall x: x \in A$ or $x \in B$

Def 2: $f(A)=\{Y \in Y \mid \Rightarrow x \in X, y=f(x)\}=\{f(x): x \in A$}

let $f: X \rightarrow Y $ be a function.

Then $A, B$ $\subseteq X$.

Prove: $f(A \cup B)=f(A) \cup f(B)$

For all $y \in$  $f(A \cup B)$ then by Def 2, there exist $x \in A \cup B$ and by def 1 it follows that $x \in A$ or $x \in B$.
with out the loss of generality assume that $x\in$ $A$, then by def 2 $y \in f(A)$ and it follows by def 1 that $y \in f(A) \cup f(B)$

Following answer I would need to prove the left implication:

lef $y \in f(A) \cup f(B)$, then by def 1. $Y \in f(A)$ or $Y \in \mathcal{C}(B)$ WLOG assume that $y \in f(A)$ then by def 2.

$\exists x: x \in A$ and by def 1 $x\in A \cup B$ which by def 2 then $y \in f(A \cup B)$

Comment: You only proved that $f(A\cup B)\subset f(A)\cup f(B)$. Also, why assuming WLOG that $y\in f(A)$ ? You have that $y=f(x)$ and $x\in A$ or $x\in B$, therefore $y\in f(A)\cup f(B)$.

Comment: @Surb could be that $ y \in f(B)$

Comment: @Surb Are you saying it is sufficient to state that $y \in F(A \Union B)$

Comment: I don't think Def 1 makes sense.  Def 1: $x \in A \cup B: \Leftrightarrow \forall x: x \in A$ or $x \in B.$ When you say $\forall x$, what do you mean? For all $ x$ in what?

Comment: Assuming this was a typo so I changed it from $y\in (A\cup B)$ to $y\in f(A\cup B)$

Comment: I echoed @Surb’s comment in my answer.

Comment: @Surb are you able to have a look at the proof now to see if it holds?

Comment: it works $ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have shown, is that $y\in f(A\cup B)\to y\in f(A)\cup f(B)$, but that *doesn’t* imply that they are equal, only that $f(A\cup B)\subseteq f(A)\cup f(B).$ In order to prove that they are equal you **also** have to show the *reverse* direction, namely: $y\in f(A)\cup f(B)\to y\in f(A\cup B)$, or in other words $f(A) \cup f(B)\subseteq f(A\cup B)$.

Comment: are you able to have a look at the proof now after updating it from your comments

Comment: Yes, it works. @ALEXANDER